# Add Hidden Model List To Razor Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I am creating a wizard and I need to propagate a list that I have created.  The list is of my Contact model.  I need to put this in the form so that when I post back to the controller on my final step I can have the list of Contacts as part of the wizard model (it just returns null now).  For other simple form objects I use a HiddenFor to keep the data in the model.  This doesn't work because a hidden for is just a text box and I have a complex object.

I considered creating a DropDownListFor and wrapping it in a hidden div.  This is just patchwork and would actually take a bit of work to get DropDownListFor to accept another object type (if it would work at all).

I have considered saving the list to Session["Contacts"], but that does not seem like the proper MVC way to go.  Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Thanks,
TJ

--UPDATE--

In response to merekel I am adding more detail to clarify where I am having the issue.  This list is not modified by the user and will not display on the form.  I create the list in one of my wizard steps and save it to my model like this.

View Model

```
public class WizardViewModel
{
    //...
    public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Controller code

```
//Step 4 in the wizard
model.ContactList = CALL FUNCTION THAT CREATES LIST BASED ON FORM SELECTIONS

//other calculations needed for step 5

//Save Contacts for later
Session["Contacts"] = model.ContactList;


//Step 5 in the wizard

//Readd the contacts to the model
model.ContactList = (List<Contact>)Session["Contacts"];

//Save the model to pass to the report page
//My report viewer is on an ASPX page so I am passing all the data here with a session
Session["ReportModel"] = model;
```

The session save works as expected.  It just does not seem like I should be using sessions to save data from page to page with MVC.  I need to when going from MVC to ASPX, so I am not worried about Session["ReportModel"] only Session["Contacts"].  Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You are going to have to post what your actions look like and what your model is on the view. Is `model` in your controller code of type `WizardViewModel`? It still isn't very clear at what step your controller code is in the process. Is the controller code you posted for creating the form view?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that posts like this will help [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3), [2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx). There are many posts similar to these on how to post back lists.

Are these contacts populated from your form or are they global contacts?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I modified my post to clarify what I did not properly describe.