# How to retrieve data from multiple partial views using the same model within the same view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC but I'm creating a web site like [Edfa3ly.com](http://Edfa3ly.com) the user should make an order with multiple items .. I used `@Ajax.ActionLink` to make him add another item (by calling the same partial view again) the problem is: when click save order it saves only 1 item (it overwrites the 1st one) i don't know how to save the first item then take the other one.. I tried to put `@Html.ActionLink` but it doesn't validate the form and also it passes a null model.

That's the view:

```asp
@model CSP1225.Models.OrderItemsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MakeOrder";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}




@using (Html.BeginForm("MakeOrder","Order",Model)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div>
    <div class="inner">

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.fees)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.fees)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.totalPrice)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.totalPrice)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.totalWeight)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.NewOrderDetails.totalWeight)



  @Html.Partial("NewItem",Model.itemAdded)

       <div id="anotherItem">

       </div>


       @Ajax.ActionLink("another item", 
                 "NewItem",
                 new AjaxOptions { 
                 UpdateTargetId = "anotherItem"})
    </div>
            <input type="Submit" value="Save Order" />
        </div>
        </div>

}
```

That's the partial view:

```asp
@model CSP1225.Models.ItemDetails


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>Item Details</legend>
        <div class="inner">
          @Html.ValidationSummary()

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.itemName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.itemName)


        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.itemUrl)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.itemUrl)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.quantity)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.quantity)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.weight)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.weight)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.unitprice)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.unitprice)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Notes)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Notes)
<br />

        @Html.ActionLink("save item","NewItem","Order",Model.itemAdded,null)


</div>

        </div>
}
```

and that's my model:

```
        public class OrderItemsModel
        {
            public NewOrder NewOrderDetails { get; set; }
            public ItemDetails itemAdded { get; set; }

        }

     public class ItemDetails
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "name Required")]
            public string itemName { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "URL Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Url)]
            public string itemUrl { get; set; }
            public int quantity { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "price Required")]
            [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
            public Decimal unitprice { get; set; }
            public string color { get; set; }
            public string Size { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "weight Required")]
            public double weight { get; set; }
            public string Notes { get; set; }
            public IList<Item> itemList { get; set; }
        }

     public class NewOrder
        {

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Total weight")]
            public double totalWeight { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Total Price")]
            public decimal totalPrice { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Fees")]
            public double fees { get; set; }

            public DateTime OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

that's the controller:

```
 Order ord = new Order();
 ItemDetails it;
        List<Item> lstItem = new List<Item>();
       decimal tp = 0;
        double tw = 0;
        double f = 5.5;


    public PartialViewResult NewItem(OrderItemsModel item)
        {


return PartialView();

        }

    public PartialViewResult NewItemAdd(ItemDetails item)
    {
     if (item !=null)
     {
        it = new ItemDetails();
        it = item;
        CDB1225Entities _context = new CDB1225Entities();
        Item i = new Item();

        if (it != null)
        {
            i.ItemName = item.itemName;
            i.ItemURL = item.itemUrl;
            i.Notes = item.Notes;
            i.Price = item.unitprice;
            i.Quantity = item.quantity;
            i.Weight = item.weight;
            _context.Items.Add(i);

            lstItem.Add(i);
            tw = tw + i.Weight;
            tp = tp + i.Price;
            if (i.Weight >= 0.5)
            {
                f = (i.Weight / 0.5) * f;

            }
            else
            {
                f = 5.5;
            }

            item = null;
        }
            return PartialView();
        }
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using custom editor templates instead of partial views? That should stop your names from clashing

Comment: i did.. but it loads one item only as well !!

Comment: Where is your Action code which is called by your ActionLink

Comment: i added it to the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the HTML code that you're actually writting?
you are writing 2 `<form>`, the Details inside the `Makeorder`, the idea is that you just append form controls, not a new `<form>` tag, as your `@using (Html.BeginForm())` call does:

Delete the `Html.BeginForm` from the partial view (it will be embed inside the main form) and you need to follow up the same name convention as you do in your object, in other words:

you will call `itemName` from your Model as `Model.itemAdded.itemName` so you will need to follow the same convention in your partial views:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <legend>Item Details</legend>


    <label for="itemAdded.itemName">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.itemName", Model.itemName)
    </label>

    <label for="itemAdded.itemUrl">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.itemUrl", Model.itemUrl)
    </label>

    <label for="itemAdded.quantity">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.quantity", Model.quantity)
    </label>

    <label for="itemAdded.weight">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.weight", Model.weight)
    </label>

    <label for="itemAdded.unitprice">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.unitprice", Model.unitprice)
    </label>

    <label for="itemAdded.Notes">
       @Html.TextBox("itemAdded.Notes", Model.Notes)
    </label>


</div>
```

Do not understand the `Save` button as the main form can have that Save button itself, just add it there.

In your `Controller` that has the Action for `Orders/MakeOrder` all you need to have is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(OrderItemsModel model) 
{
    // here your model will have all the passed form inputs
}
```

Comment: "Save" Button is for saving the item in the order and add another one.. but you mean i use the OrderItemsModel or ItemDetails model?? in the partial view..

Comment: There is no `IEnumberable` in your model, in other words, there is no Collection in the model you show in your question, for such, it's not understood that you have a "multiple" anywhere!
If you want to had multiple series of an object, I already answered several questions about that long time ago as that's a normal question. Will try to find...

Comment: Please post the entire Object Model (including the `List<T>` so we can help you better)

Comment: then you should use this answer to complete your form: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9307173/28004