# ViewModel Properties null In From post mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this viewmodel:

```
public class PostRequirements 
    {
        public List<Question> _questions { get; set; }
        public List<string> _documents { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my main view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePostReq", "Post", 
                       FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    if (Model._questions != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_appQuestions.cshtml", Model._questions)
    }
    if (Model._documents != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_appDocuments.cshtml", Model._documents)
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
}
```

Here is my `_appQuestions.cshtml` view :

```
@model IEnumerable<Core.Model.Question>

<input type="hidden" name="ApplId" value="1" />
<h3>Questions</h3>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td style="width: 70%;">

                <textarea id="@item.Id" name="@item.Id" style="width: 300px;height: 70px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }


</table>
```

Here is post action:

```
public ActionResult SavePostReq(PostRequirements preq)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Result", new { id = 2 });
            }
```

My model preq is not null but the `_questions` and `_documents` are coming null in the post.

Comment: Please show how you are using Model._questions & Model._documents inside the partial views.

Comment: ok, let me post them as well

Comment: @goths  i posted my partial view, kindly see it

Comment: use `[HttpPost]` in action header

Comment: how you are using two model in main view "Model._questions & Model._documents" ? I guess this is being passed null.

Answer (score 0):

Directly pass Model object (instead of Model._questions) to both the partial views and use Model._questions[i].Title in a for loop as shown in the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

You Action is expecting `PostRequirements` but you are passing either `Question` or `Documents`. I think the viewModel is better when you want to display data but when retreiving you must customize the binder. have a look on this page [Custom Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)
I hope it will help you.