# Export search results to excel in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I have following controller. When i search for a specific grade i get a list. What i want is to export this result to excel. I have my export button works fine. But the only thing is that it tries to export everything in db to excel when i click on it. What i want is to export only the results. Any idea?

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            if (searchBy == "ID")
            {
                return View(db.students.Where(x => x.id==search).ToList());
            }
            else if (searchBy == "grade")
            {
                return View(db.students.Where(x => x.grade == search).ToList());
            }
        else
        {
            return View(db.students.Take(0));
        }
    }

     public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = db.students.ToList();
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=students.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
```

And this is the part in my index view:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="Export" id="Export" value="Export" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ExportData()` action is just retrieving every result from `db.students`, it doesn't know what is in your view.
Assuming your list of students has all the data you want, you could either post the entire list to your action, e.g.

```
public ActionResult ExportData(List<Student> students)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = students;
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=students.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

Or you could pass your search parameters and filter the database accordingly, e.g.

```
public ActionResult ExportData(string searchBy, string search)
{

    GridView gv = new GridView();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        if (searchBy == "ID")
        {
            gv.DataSource = db.students.Where(x => x.id==search).ToList();
        }
        else if (searchBy == "grade")
        {
            gv.DataSource = db.students.Where(x => x.grade == search).ToList();
        }
    }
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=students.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

And don't forget to post the necessary data from your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vitor. I tried the first one. I am getting only 2 div tags in my excel. Any idea why?

Comment: I forgot POSTing a `List` (or `IEnumerable`) is not trivial. Try to follow along with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9307173/1397117