# How do I get my ActionResult method to return a file for download and the Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, httpresponse

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068430/1466627) answer, by using `Response` to return the Excel XLS file, the `ActionResult` returns the `PartialView` as it is supposed to, but then it does not give me a XLS file to download.

Form on SearchItems.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "grid_searchitems" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Entity Search</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Select an Item Purpose:")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBox(
                "Purpose",
                new MultiSelectList((Model as List<MyWeb.Models.SearchItemModel>).Select(a => a.Purpose).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(a => a)),
                new {
            @class = "chosen-select",
                    data_placeholder = "Choose a function code"
                })
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="ButtonType"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="gridContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_SearchItems") @* See _SearchItem.cshtml (below) for WebGrid *@
</div>
```

_SearchItem.cshtml Partial View containing the `WebGrid`

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid_searchitems", rowsPerPage: 25);
}

<style type="text/css">
    .webgrid-table td {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>

<div id="grid_searchitems">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
        headerStyle: "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", "Item Name"),
            grid.Column("Purpose", "Purpose"),
        )
    )
</div>
```

ActionResult Method that is hit when the Submit button is clicked

```
public ActionResult SearchModes(string[] Purpose = null) {
    List<SearchItemModel> items = DBContext.Items.ToList();
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = items;
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SearchResults.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End(); // <-- Is this where the "download" is supposed to be received on the client?

    ViewData.Model = items;
    //AJAX request is generated when submit button clicked
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        // Return only the changed entities
        return PartialView("_SearchItems"); // <-- This works
    }
    else {
        // Return entire view
        return View();
    }
}
```

In the end, I want to be able to have the user click `Search` then ability to save the results XLS file, while having the results shown in the returned `Partial View`. I'd like to be able, eventually, to have two Submit buttons, where one is just for querying, and the other for querying and exporting (reason why I'm using the `name` attribute).

Comment: When you say `// <--This works`, the excel file is generated AND the view is returned?

Comment: Anyway you should separate your actions, that's why you have ActionResult, PartialViewResult, FileResult, JsonResult. Doing everything in the same action is so messy...

Comment: An `ActionResult` action *can only provide one result* to the browser. It can return *either* a view (partial or fill) *or* a `FileResult`, but not both. You need to separate your actions and remember that a file download will normally leave the previous page/view onscreen so that does not have to be returned at the same time.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico The Partial View is returned. How would I do this in two? Does that mean I would need to have two identical forms with identical `ActionResults` except that one returns a `PartialView` and the other returns a File?

Comment: Let me make an example of how I would do it.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I'd like to reuse the same form, but I wasn't sure if you could have two submit buttons that pointed at different Actions.

Comment: You could change the form action URL, using javascript, but that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using jquery to simplify the answer**

Considering an initial problem that I have a **Search** and **Export** functionality based on a filter criteria selected by the user in my view.

The **Search** operation is simple, just a regular form with my action being called when submitting the from:

MyView.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(..)) 
...
```

The action that will be called by my form will just return my PartialView:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchModes([form-fields]) {
   ...
   return Partial(...)
```

Everything working so far. Now I want to provide an **Export** functionality based in the previous form fields. I would make a GET call with the form fields as the query string:

MyView.cshtml

```
<button id="exportButton"...></button>

$(function () {
    $("#exportButton").click(exportMyForm);
});

function exportMyForm() {
    var $form = $("form");

    // Changed the line below (see @comments)
    // var result = decodeURIComponent($.param($form.serializeFormJSON())); 
    var result = $form.serialize();

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("MyController", "MyExportAction")?" + result;
}
```

And finally my **Export** action:

```
public FileResult MyExportAction([form-fields]) {
   ...
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SearchResults.xls");
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
   ...
   return File(...)
```

That's the idea. Both actions will receive the form values. The first one using the Ajax form post and the second one with a simple GET. Because of the content disposition, a new file will be downloaded and the user will stay in the same screen.

Hope it helps :)

**Edit:**

I think it is not clear, the `[form-fields]` holder should be a view model with the form representation, the same one for the regular **Search** and the **Export** actions.

Comment: `$("form")` is the ID of the form?

Comment: I am using jquery to simplify the problem. $("form") will return the first form in your document (you should have only one). However if you set an ID for the form, you can use $("#[form-id]") like I did with the button.

Comment: I got this working with using `var result = $form.serialize();` instead of `var result = decodeURIComponent($.param($form.serialize()));`

Comment: Hi as @gustavodidomenico has pointed out " a new file will be downloaded and the user will stay in the same screen." I want the same thing just that i want the screen to refresh. I am returning a file in my controller action but i also want to refresh my Main view. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Saurabh, I would play with window.location.reload(), after setting the href to the download url. You can perform this using plain javascript. Or even, open the exported file into another tab.