# Export filtered results to excel in MVC 4 (no web form)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I am unable to export the filtered results to an Excel file. I am just learning ASP.Net and MVC.

I have looked at the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068061/export-search-results-to-excel-in-mvc-4), but I can't get it to work. I am not very sure how to use the EditorTemplate mentioned in another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3/9307173#9307173).

Currently, when I export, all the data gets exported regardless of the filter. How do I  export what is displayed on the view to an Excel file, without using web forms?

Thank you..

Here is my view, Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExportToExcel.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Student",FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Name: @Html.TextBox("NameSearch")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel","ExportToExcel")
        </p>
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Marks)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Marks)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

In my controller, I have implemented the followings:

```
public ActionResult Index(string nameSearch)
{
    var students = from m in db.Students
                     select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameSearch))
    {
        students = students.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(nameSearch));
    }

    return View(students);
}

public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();

    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameSearch))
    //{
    //    gv.DataSource = db.Students.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(nameSearch)).ToList();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    gv.DataSource = db.Students.ToList();
    //}
    gv.DataSource = db.Students.ToList();
    gv.DataBind();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=StudentList.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gv.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, managed to find an answer. Original [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1991866.aspx?Export%20filtered%20results%20to%20excel%20in%20MVC%204).

Basically, store the search result in session. Then, retrieve the list from session during export.

Answer (score 1):

```
     public ActionResult ExportExcel()

    {

        var EmployeeList = (List<Employee>)Session["EmployeeList"];
        //var EmployeeList = Session["EmployeeList"] as List<Product>;
        //var EmployeeList = Session["EmployeeList"];

        GridView grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = EmployeeList;

        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Employees.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```