# How to edit List contained in ViewModel ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I am working on a project where I have to create a shopping cart using ASP.NET MVC project.

I am stuck trying to edit values which I have stored in a property of a custom ViewModel, which is a list of objects.

The model looks like this:

```
public class ShoppingCartVM
{
    public List<ProductVM> CartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public ShoppingCartVM() {}
    public ShoppingCartVM(List<ProductVM> cartItems) {
        this.CartItems = cartItems;
        this.SubTotal = CalculateSubTotal();
        this.Tax = CalculateTax();
        this.Total = CalulateTotal();
        // CalculateItemCost(); // will update the total cost field of VM
    }

    public decimal CalculateSubTotal()
    {
        decimal? total = 0.00m;
        foreach(var item in this.CartItems)
        {
            total += item.totalCost;
        }
        return (decimal)total;
    }

    public decimal CalculateTax()
    {
        decimal tax = this.SubTotal * 0.07m;
        return tax;
    }

    public decimal CalulateTotal()
    {
        decimal total = this.SubTotal + this.Tax;
        return total;
    }       
}
```

And in the view I am currently trying to loop through list and create editable fields for some of the values like this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ShoppingCartVM</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @{ 
        int i = 0;
        // List<ShoppingCartApp.Models.ProductVM> CartItems = new List<ShoppingCartApp.Models.ProductVM>();
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {

        // try to build up an array and add it to
        <span> @item.productID </span>
        @Html.Hidden("Model.CartItems[" + @i + " ].productID",@item.productID);
        <span> @item.productName </span>
        @Html.Hidden("Model.CartItems[" + @i + " ].productName", Model.CartItems[@i].productName);
        @*<input type="number" value="@item.quantity" name="Model.CartItems[@i].quantity" />*@
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CartItems[@i].quantity);
        <span> @item.price </span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CartItems[@i].price);
        <span> @item.totalCost </span> 
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CartItems[@i].totalCost);
        <br />
        i++;
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CartItems); @*probably wont have updated values*@
    <br />
    @Html.Raw("<p> Sub total: " + Model.SubTotal + "</p>")
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubTotal)
    @Html.Raw("<p> Tax: " + Model.Tax + "</p>")
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Tax)
    @Html.Raw("<p> Total: " + Model.Total + "</p>")
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Total)
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Any thoughts on this? I was storing the list in the VM to try and reduce the "business logic" in the View but this seems to be creating more for me.

Your help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Use a `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop, or better use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the model represented by the `CartItems` property (and you have not shown us the model).

Comment: Yes, pasted in the wrong code. My mistake.

Comment: When you say editor template you mean @html.editorfor ? How can i use that while inside a loop?

Comment: Based on your edit, you need to remove `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CartItems)` - that will just cause binding to fail (look at the html it generates. And adding hidden inputs for `SubTotal`, `Total` and `Tax` are pointless (and surely this calculations are based on the quantity which you never take into account).

Comment: You dont use an `EditorTemplate` in a loop. You use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CartItems)` to generate the html for each item in the collection (and create an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ProductVM`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen I will look into and post the solution here when I am done

Answer (score 1):

So to access values I changed it to a for loop and then created either an editorfor or a hidden for each field i need a value for. This way when I hit "submit", it will place all these values into the object I specified in the Post action method.

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CartItems[i].productID);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CartItems[i].productID);

        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CartItems[i].productName);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CartItems[i].productName);

        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CartItems[i].price);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CartItems[i].price);

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CartItems[i].quantity);

        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CartItems[i].totalCost);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CartItems[i].totalCost);                     
    }
```

Will ginerate fields with the correct name so asp.net can put into the same object when I post.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewCart(ShoppingCartVM cart)
    {
        return View(cart);
    }
```

This link was very helpful.

[Posting to a list<modeltype> MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3)

Thanks,

Matt