# Displaying, Editing, and Posting a List ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to follow this question, [Posting to a list<modeltype> MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306246/posting-to-a-listmodeltype-mvc3), but I was running into a roadblock.

I want to display the full contents of a table, allow editing to that table, then submit it back to controller to save edits.

Specifically, the error I'm getting here is on `Model.ClonePosts.Count`:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ClonePosts' and no accessible extension method 'ClonePosts' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found

Aside from that immediate problem, I'm not sure that have the binding correct. Will changes made in the View get posted correctly?

Thank you in advance

Model:

```
public class ClonePost
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string ItemData { get; set; }
    public int ItemSelected { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
public class ReviewCloneVM
{
    public List<ClonePost> ClonePosts { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM>

<h1>ReviewClone</h1>
<table class="table">
    @*foreach (var item in Model)*@
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClonePosts.Count; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].PostNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemData)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemSelected)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Clone" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult>ReviewClone(string zero = "230323-0")
    {
        ...
        // now call up the full table for review and edit
        var cloned = _context.ClonePosts.OrderByDescending(m => m.PostNumber);

        return View(await cloned.ToListAsync());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult>ReviewClone(ReviewCloneVM reviewCloneVM)
    {
        try
        {
            // other stuff
            return RedirectToAction("PostDetail", "Post", new { zero = "230323-0" });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(reviewCloneVM);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `@model IEnumerable<AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM>` instead of `@model AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM` in  your view?

Comment: @NickFleetwood You need to assign your `ClonePosts` to the DB result. Check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `Model` type from `@model IEnumerable<AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM>` to `AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM` and then access the `ClonePosts` from the Model :

```
@model AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM

<h1>ReviewClone</h1>
<table class="table">
  @if(Model !=null)
  {
      @*foreach (var item in Model)*@
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClonePosts.Count; i++) 
      {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].PostNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemData)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemSelected)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Clone" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     }    
  }   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Your `Controller` method will be:

```
public async Task<IActionResult>ReviewClone(string zero = "230323-0")
{
    ...
    ReviewCloneVM model=new ReviewCloneVM();
    // now call up the full table for review and edit
    var cloned = _context.ClonePosts.OrderByDescending(m => m.PostNumber);
    model.ClonePosts =await cloned.ToListAsync();
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your View, You need to use

```
@model AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM
```

as the model, So try to change your  code like:

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ReviewClone(string zero = "230323-0")
        {
            
        //now call up the full table for review and edit
            var cloned =  _context.ClonePosts.OrderByDescending(m => m.PostNumber).ToList();
            ReviewCloneVM vm = new ReviewCloneVM()
            {
                ClonePosts = cloned,
            };
            return View(vm);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model AURA.ViewModels.ReviewCloneVM

<h1>ReviewClone</h1>
<form method="post">
    @*foreach (var item in Model)*@
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClonePosts.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].PostNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemData)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClonePosts[i].ItemSelected)
            </td>
            
        </tr>
        <br />
    }

    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </td>
   
</form>
```

**Demo**:

[image]